# can FND_GLOBAL.CONC_REQUEST_ID this be used in shell script to fetch the request_id of concurrent program

Tags: shell, sqlplus

Is this the right way to fetch request id in shell script

```
v_request_id=`sqlplus -s /nolog <<END 
connect $FCP_LOGIN
set echo off
set head off
set verify off
set feedback off
set trimspool on
SELECT  FND_GLOBAL.CONC_REQUEST_ID
FROM  DUAL
END`
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely.
1.) put a semicolon after dual

2.) why use the old ugly backticks?

3.) make it more compact: put all the set options in one line:
SET echo off head off feed off verify off trimspool on

4.) Why break the SELECT into several lines?

5.) You will get more than one line as result, because sqlplus always creates an empty header line, so you have to get rid of that. Maybe by using tail -1

6.) If your result is numerical, you are in for a surprise: sqlplus will pad it with spaces. Best way: convert it into a string with TO_CHAR

So the result could be this here:

```
v_request_id=$(sqlplus -s /nolog <<END | tail -1
connect $FCP_LOGIN
set echo off head off verify off feedback off trimspool on
SELECT TO_CHAR(FND_GLOBAL.CONC_REQUEST_ID) FROM DUAL;
END)
```